# I need to iterate user-data in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-ngx-module

I am reading the ngnix client certificate and storing it in a local variable.

```lua
local client_cert = openssl_x509.new(ngx.var.ssl_client_raw_cert)
local subject = client_cert:getSubject()
```

I need to get the common name from the subject, how can I get it?

Comment: Which module are you using for `openssl_x509.new`? What's the functionality of `getSubject()`?

Comment: I am using local openssl_x509 = require "openssl.x509" and 
local openssl_store = require "openssl.x509.store". getSubject() is giving some certificate details : CN=blr2preman1, client: 10.120.10.151, server: kong, request: "GET /example HTTP/1.1", host: "10.120.9.149:8443"

Comment: Which type has subject after `client_cert:getSubject()`? I can't figure it out, only by reading the doc. If you get a table object, you can simply use `subject.CN`.
In case of string (for instance after `subject:text()`), following lua pattern should work `string.match(urvar, 'CN=(.*),')`.